# telebot перепись одну переменнную

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

```
есть одна переменная но если я ее меняю то скрипт не работает. пример:
import telebot
import random

bot = telebot.TeleBot('xxxxxxxx')
keyboard1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard1.row('Инвентарь', 'Идти', 'Статы')

h = 10
b = 8
c = 5

d1 = int(random.uniform(1, 10))  #Ж
d2 = int(random.uniform(1, 10))  #A
d3 = int(random.uniform(1, 10))  #Т

d4 = int(random.uniform(5, 20))  #Ж
d5 = int(random.uniform(5, 20))  #А
d6 = int(random.uniform(5, 20))  #Т

d7 = int(random.uniform(10, 30))  #Ж
d8 = int(random.uniform(10, 30))  #А
d9 = int(random.uniform(10, 30))  #Т

dm1 = ['Волк', 'Заяц', 'Кабан', 'Лиса', 'Шакал', 'Мышь', 'Носорог', 'Лось', 'Белый медведь', 'Верблюд', 'Гиена']
dm = random.choice(dm1)

dm2 = ['Разбойник', 'Леший', 'Ведьма', 'Вампир', 'Зомби', 'Скелет-воин', 'Скелет-маг', 'Мумии', 'Призраки', 'Духи']
dm3 = random.choice(dm2)

dm4 = ['Василиск', 'Гарпия', 'Дракон', 'Кентавр', ' Минотавр', 'Пегас', 'Циклоп', 'Единорог', 'Валькирия', 'Феникс']
dm5 = random.choice(dm4)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '''!Вы появились!Ваша расса:человекповышайте уровень и становитесь сильнее.Удачи
    ''', reply_markup=keyboard1)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'инвентарь':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '''
Броня: шлем +2 , нагрудник +3 , перчатки +1 , ботинки +2 
Оружие: клинок +5
Предметы и тд:
10 золотых монет
''')
    elif message.text.lower() == 26:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'''
''')

    elif message.text.lower() == 'статы':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'''
Жизни: {h} - и тут
Атака: {c}
Броня: {b}
''')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'идти':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '''
подземелья 1 уровня - 1
подземелья 2 уровня - 2
подземелья 3 уровня - 3
    ''')

    elif message.text.lower() == '1':
        dm = random.choice(dm1)
        d1 = int(random.uniform(1, 10))
        d2 = int(random.uniform(1, 10))
        d3 = int(random.uniform(1, 10))
        hp = d1 + d3 - c
        d = h + b - d2
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'''
На вас напал(а): {dm} 
Ж - {d1} 
A - {d2} 
З - {d3} 
''')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'''
Жизни {dm}: {hp}
Ваши жизни: {d}
''')
        h = hp - ошибка здесь

    elif message.text.lower() == '2':
        dm3 = random.choice(dm2)
        d4 = int(random.uniform(5, 20))
        d5 = int(random.uniform(5, 20))
        d6 = int(random.uniform(5, 20))
        hp = d4 + d6 - c
        d = h + b - d4
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'''
На вас напал(а): {dm3} 
Ж - {d4} 
A - {d5} 
З - {d6} 
''')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'''
    Жизни {dm3}: {hp}
    Ваши жизни: {d}
    ''')
    elif message.text.lower() == '3':
        dm5 = random.choice(dm4)
        d7 = int(random.uniform(10, 30))  # Ж
        d8 = int(random.uniform(10, 30))  # А
        d9 = int(random.uniform(10, 30))  # Т
        hp = d7 + d9 - c
        d = h + b - d8
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'''
    На вас напал(а): {dm5} 
Ж - {d7} 
А - {d8} 
З - {d9} 
    ''')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'''
    Жизни {dm5}: {hp}
    Ваши жизни: {d}
    ''')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'люблю':
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAADAgADZgkAAnlc4gmfCor5YbYYRAI')
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['sticker'])
def sticker_id(message):
    print(message)


bot.polling()
```

Comment: Что значит - не работает? Возникает ошибка? Если да - то приведите полный текст ошибки. Если нет - то подробно опишите, какое поведение вы ожидаете получить и чем реальное поведение от него отличается.

Comment: И где у вас первый раз возникает переменная h? Если приведённый фрагмент кода находится внутри функции, а переменная h объявлена за её пределами, то скорее всего проблема именно в том, что нельзя внутри функции просто так присваивать значение переменной, объявленной за её пределами.